# Exception in ShowDialog() extern .cs C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to show a "messagebox" to the user and in case it requires to use a custom path, “FolderBrowserDialog" must be opened.

The problem is that in the code behind my page I use the library "System.Web.UI.WebControls" so I cannot do it directly and what I do is call the function in an external class that does contain the library of "System .Windows.Forms ".

Showing the "message box" works well, but if the user chooses to open the file explorer, is there an error, any solution, or recommendation?

Code Behind

```
[STAThread]
    protected void btnDescargarExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxExtension messageBox = new MessageBoxExtension();
        string path = messageBox.ShowMessage();
    }
```

MessageBoxExtension.cs

```
[STAThread]
    public string ShowMessage()
    {
        try
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("¿Guardar en la carpeta de Descargas?", "Guardar Excel", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
                {
                    fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
                    DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog(); //Linea del error 
                    if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
                    {
                        return fbd.SelectedPath;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                String home = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
                return home + @"\Downloads\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm").ToString() + ".xlsx";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Error Message

```
System.Threading.ThreadStateException: 'The current thread must be set to Single Thread Apartment (STA) mode in order to make OLE calls. Make sure the Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked. This exception is raised only if a debugger is attached to the process.'
```

Comment: Put `[STAThread]` on your `Main` method.

Comment: If this is an ASP.NET application, you should not be using `FolderBrowserDialog` at all! That will launch a dialog box on the server where the web site is running, not on the end user's machine where the browser is running. The only reason it might work for you is if you are running it on localhost as a developer.

Comment: Yes, it is an ASP.NET application. You know what would be the best way to open a dialog box? @JohnWu